Lubuntu 24.04 boots to black screen
I've installed (by now even reinstalled) Lubuntu 24.04 and it boots pretty weirdly.
Most of the time it boots into a black screen only on very rare occasions it does not.
After looking around for a bit I've added nomodeset to this boot option thingy.
Additional drivers shows nothing I could install and when executing "ubuntu-drivers install" I get "All the available drivers are already installed."
The ubuntu-drivers debug command gets me this: debug output
But other people told me it may be a boot parameter issue and I should check grub.cfg if something is misconfigured. I sadly don't have any idea of boot parameters so I'll just post the content of the file here.
Would be nice if someone knows a fix so my PC boots with display output (without having to use nomodeset or recovery mode) and my graphics performance is normal again.
I have an AMD GPU and Intel CPU.
My GPU model is Radeon RX 6650 XT.

nomodeset stops any video drivers you have installed from being used and uses a generic driver from the kernel. The low performance is expected. It is to only be used till the issue is fixed and then you remove it from Grub. Please edit the question and add the model of the AMD GPU so someone can help you find the right video driver.

Thanks for the reply @David.
After I updated my question yesterday I looked up some drivers for my graphics card today myself, but on the AMD website for example there doesn't seem to be a driver for Ubuntu 24.04 for my graphics card.
Where else could I look or can I just download a driver for an older Ubuntu version?
